# Find the average value of $f(x,y)=x^2 y$ in the triangular region with vertices $(1,1), (2,0), (0,1)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there any way to find the average value without applying the change of variable formula? The triangle is not a type-1 or type-2 region, right? (Its area is 1, but I'm mostly concerned with the limits of integration). We would have to split it into two parts, but is the average value function linear?

$$\frac{\iint_D f(x,y)dA}{\iint_D dA} \stackrel{?}{=} \int_0^1\int_{1-x/2}^{1+x} x^2y \ dydx + \int_1^2\int_{1-x/2}^{-x+2} x^2y \ dydx$$

I'm super confused.

Comment: It’s easier to compute if you see that $y$ goes from $0$ to $1$, and then, at $y,$ $x$ goes from $2-2y$ to $2-y.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The type of the triangle does not matter as long as you show it in the integral bounds. Note that only the second term of integral you have written is needed.$$\iint_D f(x,y)dS=\int_1^2 \int_{1-{x\over 2}}^{1-x} x^2ydydx$$which could also have been written as $$\iint_D f(x,y)dS=\int_0^1 \int_{2-2y}^{2-y}x^2ydxdy$$